# Mocha: Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves

Tags: javascript, mongoose, mocha.js

This code:

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/users_test',{useNewUrlParser:true});

mongoose.connection
    .once('open',()=>console.log('Good to go!'))
    .on('error',(error)=>{
        console.log('Warning',error);
    })

beforeEach((done)=>{
    mongoose.connection.collections.users.drop(()=>{
        done();
    })
})
```

yields Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

Does anyone have any clue why? As far as I can tell, mongoose.connection.collections.users.drop(()=>{
        done();
    }) should call done() almost instantly.

Comment: What about full credentials in this format - mongodb://username:password@localhost:portnum/dbName

Answer (score 1):

You could increase the timeout of the `Mocha` tests, as the `mongoose.connection.collections` is an async function and a `network call` can take longer time to finish.

Example.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/users_test", { useNewUrlParser: true });

mongoose.connection
  .once("open", () => console.log("Good to go!"))
  .on("error", error => {
    console.log("Warning", error);
  });

describe("something", function() {
  this.timeout(5000);
  beforeEach(done => {
    mongoose.connection.collections.users.drop(() => {
      done();
    });
  });
  // tests...
});
```